# How to perform mean differences in Linear Probability Model in Stata

Tags: regression, stata

I was wondering if I am able to perform a mean differences for LPM 
with binary dependent variable using diff() in stata.

Dependent variable: child's education (High or Low)

Independent Variable: Father's Education (High or Low)
                      Mother's Education (High or Low)

Basically I want to test for differences between father and mother's education.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @StataMA Do you want to test that the effect on child's education of father's education and mother's education is the same?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Yes Please that is what I want to test for.....I was wondering how to test it...

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov in stata that is...I spent hours on this but could not get anything done. t-test and f-test would not work so I was wondering how can I test this very easily....

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple Wald test that two coefficients are equal or construct a difference of coefficients like this after fitting an LPM:

```
sysuse auto, clear

foreach var of varlist price mpg {
    xtile high_`var' = `var', nq(2)
    replace high_`var'=high_`var'-1
    table high_`var', c(mean `var' min `var' max `var')
}

reg foreign i.high_price i.high_mpg weight, robust
test 1.high_price=1.high_mpg
lincom 1.high_price-1.high_mpg
```

The way you can learn about this is that Stata has pdf manuals. Every estimation command has an entry, and all the things you can do after using that command also have an entry, under `command_name_postestimation`. For example, for `regress`, type `help regress_postestimation`. Clicking on the the blue links will open the relevant instructions, examples, and formulas. You want a simple linear hypothesis test.